# returned value inside If statement curly bracket and its not detected

Tags: objective-c

**problem:** im using if statement inside a method and the return of this method is inside the brackets of the if statement

**what i need:** i need to use condition inside my method so i do different actions in each case. is there any way to make the return from inside the curly brackets or any other conditional method that i can use and will help me achieve my goal.

the code im facing the problem with is seen below.

any help or hint will be appreciated.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    megasearchCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[megasearchCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    if ([searchtype isEqualToString:@"a"])
    {
        //do stuff 

        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        // do stuff

        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        return cell;
    } 
}
```

Comment: What's your actual problem? Early Return is just fine.

Comment: The code you have here looks right to me.  Have you tried putting in a break point and stepping through?  Perhaps it is actually a problem with your `searchtype` variable not behaving the way you think it is.  Sidenote: you are doing `return cell;`, regardless of whether or not `[searchtype isEquadToString:@"a"]`, so you could just get rid of the two `return`s inside the `if` block and just put a single `return cell;` as the very last line of your code, just before the final curly bracket that closes the method.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe did you read all my question or only the problem part? anyways im gonna write it again in a simpler way. i have a return value inside the curly brackets of the if statement and the compiler is not detecting the returned value which makes me conclude that whatever is inside the curly bracket is used locally for the if statement and cant be used outside. im hoping that my conclusion is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, doing a `return` inside an `if` block is completely fine (just make sure you `return` in every situation - the compiler will give you a warning if you are not, and it will probably cause a crash if you run it).

What you mentioned in your rephrasing to NikolaiRuhe is correct.  If you declare a variable as part of the `// do stuff`, that variable will only exist inside the curly brackets it is declared in.  So...

```
if ([searchtype isEqualToString:@"a"])
{
    NSString *myString = @"Stuff";
    NSLog (@"%@", myString);  // This will work, 'myString' is declared inside the brackets of where it is referenced, so you're fine.
}
else
{
    NSLog (@"%@", myString); // This will **not** work, and throws an error, because there is nothing called 'myString' that is visible inside this bracket
}
```

However, you can declare things ahead of time, and they will always be visible downstream

```
NSString *myString;
if ([searchtype isEqualToString:@"a"])
{
    myString = @"Stuff";
    NSLog (@"'%@'", myString);  // outputs 'Stuff'
}
else
{
    NSLog (@"%@", myString); // Does not throw an error anymore, because 'myString' was declared above the bracket.  
    // But, since nothing is ever assigned to 'myString' in this block, the NSLog will just write out 'nil'
}
```

I hope this helps you understand what is causing your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. i understand what you mean but what if i have a return inside the brackets? in my case its not returning anything. is this normal?

Comment: Ops i just read your above comment again. ill try what u suggested and replay back.

Comment: If it is returning `nil`, then `cell` is still `nil` when you get to your `return` statement.  Do you have any `init` methods in your megasearchCell.m file?  If so, can you provide the code for that method as well?

Answer (score 1):

Your current code does not have a problem: apart from somewhat worse readability, there is nothing wrong with returning from multiple branches in your code, as long as all branches return something (in your case, they do).

You can clean up your code a little by moving `return` one level up:

```
if ([searchtype isEqualToString:@"a"]) {
    //do stuff 
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
} else {
    // do stuff
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
}
return cell;
```

However, its logic would remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if ([searchtype isEqualToString:@"a"])
{
   //do stuff 
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
}
else
{
    // do stuff
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
} 
 return cell;
```

Do it like this because you have already used if and else so it will either go in if or else at a time one will execute so it will return the cell correctly.

And if you want to do return cell within the scope of if  or else then you can do its simply but return cell also outside the scope beacuse if the condition will be true then it obviously returns from the top otherwise it will return cell.

Comment: so i can do a return from inside the if brackets, right?

Comment: @shadramon : Yes you can return from inside the brackets